# Good example using XML Publisher with a rowset

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

Does anyone know of a good example of an Application Engine program creating a rowset and then calling XML Publisher to create a report?

PeopleTools 8.49

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you've got your report defn, data source and template setup, here's the peoplecode to do it:

```
/* get report definition object */ 
&oRptDefn = create PSXP_RPTDEFNMANAGER:ReportDefn (&yourRptDefn);
&oRptDefn.Get(); 

/* pass Rowset to the report definition */ 
&oRptDefn.SetRuntimeDataRowset(&yourRowset);

/*generate report*/ 
&oRptDefn.ProcessReport (&yourTmpltID, &yourLangCd, &yourAsOfDate, &yourOutFormat); 

/*publish report */ 
&oRptDefn.PrintOutput(&yourDestinationPath);
```